# jQuery setting specific numbers in select menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this website here http://offline.raileisure.com/

on the right there are some options to book a reservation..

Where it says No. of Adults and No. of Children, I need this to be limited to x per property..

i.e. if the Station Masters House is selected its maximum occupancy is 8 people..

So if 5 Adults are selected I need the Children select menu to only show the difference between 5-8 if that makes sense..

Otherwise someone could book 5 children and 5 adults... and that would be more than the maximum 8...

Same as if the carriage is chosen the maximum occupancy is 4

Thanks

Lee

Comment: Why don't you use text-boxes and validate the numbers entered? This would be as easy as recalculate the sum each time the input field's value changes. And if the sum is exceeds the maximum, show an error and disable the submit button. (Don't forget to reenable it ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the jquery change event

http://api.jquery.com/change/

you can use this event to edit the other input and only make the options available that are still left.

here is the code that does exactly what you want:

```
var max = 8;

for (var i = 0; i <= max; i++) {
    $("#children, #adults").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(i));
}

$("#adults").change(function() {
    var sel = $("#children").val();
    $("#children").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i <= max - parseInt($("#adults").val()); i++) {
        $("#children").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(i));
    }
    $("#children").val(sel);
});

$("#children").change(function() {    
    var sel= $("#adults").val();
    $("#adults").html("");
    for (var i = 0; i <= max - parseInt($("#children").val()); i++) {
        $("#adults").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", i).text(i));
    }    
    $("#adults").val(sel);
});
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/geertvdc/ADC3a/

Comment: Good point, just remember to include something like $('#selectchildren').html($c.val()); as the "dropdown" is a comb of 'span' + 'select'

Answer (score 1):

If the `value` attribute of each `option` in your `select` lists to the same number as displayed you can get that using jQuery:

`$("#elementId option:selected").val();`

Get the value of the selected item when the first list changes, and loop through the elements in the second list, removing any that would result in a value greater than the allowed total.

**Updated:** See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/Ebgkq/3/) for an example of how it could work.

Comment: That's not what the OP asked for. He wants to remove/add option elements depending on another value, which can be done with jQuery, but not in a single line of code.

Comment: @James Allardice - Still not quite what i was after.... i don't want it to remove if adults equals 3 it needs to change the childs one to be the difference between 3 and the max ?? if that makes sense ?

Comment: its close, but it needs to be able to put the numbers back if they are reduced again on the first side.... plus it needs to work both ways

Comment: @Lee - something more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/Ebgkq/7/? It now selects the option in the 2nd list that will make the maximum when added to the selected value in the first list.

Comment: @Lee - It's not meant to be a complete working implementation, it's just meant to put you on the right track. It won't be difficult to modify it to work both ways etc.

Comment: @James - That fiddle doesn't seem to work, the second one doesn't change?

Comment: @Lee - The maximum is set to 4, so select 2 and the 2nd list will change to 2. Then select 1 in the first list, and the 2nd list will change to 3.

Comment: it doesn't here on IE8 and Google Chrome ??

Comment: @Lee - You are right about Chrome, but I'm not sure why! It works for me in IE6, 7, 8, 9 and Firefox 4. But not Chrome. Strange. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select[name="adults"]').change(function(){
        var $c = $('select[name="children"]');
        $c.html(getNewSelect($(this).val()));
        $('#selectchildren').html($c.val());
    })

function getNewSelect(val){
    var opts = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 8 - val; i ++){
        opts.push('<option val="', i+1, '">', i+1, '</option>');
    }
    return opts.join('');
}
```

In my own flavor, I would probably use a small lib I wrote for myself to make it more smooth..

```
$('select[name="adults"]').change(function(){
        var $c = $('select[name="children"]');
        var val = 8 - parseInt($(this).val());
        $c.html(Tog().map('1..'+val, 
        // this would return you something like 1..4
        // it means from 1 to 4, do a loop
            function(val){
                return Tog('option').val(val).cont(val);
            }).html()
            );
        $('#selectchildren').html($c.val());
    })
```

Comment: Thats fantastic, exactly what I was looking for, i just need to edit it to work both ways now :-) thanks

Comment: you also need to save and set the already selected value in the other selectbox otherwise it will jump back to 1 all the time. i've already included this in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's already accepted, but I worked on it so here it is: [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/hUgZE/6/). Simple implementation, works both ways.